# About the integral $\int \log (x)/(x-k) dx$ and the polylogarithm

Tags: calculus

During some calculations I ran into the integral 
$\int  \log(x)/(x-k) dx $ which Wolfram alpha happily tells me satisfies

$$ \int  \log(x)/(x-k) dx = {\rm{Li}}_2(x/k)+\log(x) \log(1-x/k)+C, $$

but not much else.
Given I saw the polylogarithm for the first time now and have only read the wikipedia page, can then be made an argument that the above is true? If so, which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polylogarithm function is initially defined by the series
$$
{\rm{Li}}_2(z):=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2},\quad |z|<1.\tag1
$$
Thus if you consider
$$
\int_0^x\frac{\log t}{t-k}dt, \quad k>1,\, |x|<1,\tag2
$$
then you may write
$$
\frac{1}{t-k}=-\frac{1}{k}\:\frac{1}{1-t/k}=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^n}{k^{n+1}}, \quad |t|<1, \, k>1,\tag3
$$ giving, by a termwise integration, which is allowed here, using the following result, obtained by an integration by parts,
$$
\int_0^xt^n\log t\:dt= -\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\log x\tag4
$$
$$
\int_0^x\frac{\log t}{t-k}dt=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{k^{n+1}}\int_0^xt^n\log t\:dt=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{k^{n+1}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}-\log x\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{k^{n+1}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.
$$ Equivalently, using $(1)$ and the standard power series for $ \displaystyle \log (1-x)$ we get
$$
\int_0^x\frac{\log t}{t-k}dt={\rm{Li}}_2\left(\frac{x}{k} \right)+\log x\log \left(1- \frac{x}{k}\right) \tag5
$$ as announced.

Comment: Holy smokes that is one neat argument. Thank you very much!